# How to prevent Index.html connection error

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

This error appears some times in run time on device and then application will close.
in some guides mentioned to add fallowing code to `config.xml`, but it makes a huge delay to start application.

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

reduce the value of preference tag so it will not take so much time

Comment: This error is not showing on every application lunch time just some times(30% cases). and I don't used that 'loadUrlTimeoutValue' tag.  how to prevent is important any why it happens is much important.